# BootCampAssistant "Install or delete Windows 7" greyed out

Tags: windows-7, mac, partitioning, boot-camp

I need to install a Windows 7 on my MacBookPro but the installation button is actually greyed out.
[image]

I first managed to install a first windows but i needed it to be bigger, so i deleted the BootCamp partition with a live GParted USB and here it is, impossible to get this again.

Here are the `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list`

[image]

And here is what my disk looks like actually

[image]

Please help me, i don't know what to do ... I got a live USB of GParted if needed.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Apple is ending support for Windows 7 through BootCamp ([source](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/03/20/new-macbook-pro-air-no-windows-7-bootcamp/)). If your model Macbook Pro is not listed [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016), then Windows 7 is no longer supported for your laptop.

Comment: Windows 7 and 8 are supported, i got a "MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)"

Answer (score -1):

Check that you're using a legitimate copy of Windows, if you are not it could be flagging it and not letting you proceed. If it's legitimate then make sure you have all the up to date drivers

Comment: I deleted the old partition, so what drivers are you exactly talking about ?
Yep, it's a legitimate one that i get thanks to my school !

Comment: Mac updates Windows drivers, you might not be able to install if your drivers are out of date. Delete them and download again, that should get you up to date and hoepfully you can install on bootcamp!

Comment: I only deleted the BootCamp partition, and since i managed to install a first windows this morning, these drivers seems to be up to date